# sort multidimensional vector of ints?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, int, multidimensional-array

Believe it or not, when I search this, I come up with nada.

How can I sort a multidimensional `vector` of `int`s by one of the "columns"?

Many thanks in advance!

**C++**

```
res = mysql_perform_query(conn, "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table1;");
std::vector< std::vector< int > > myVector;
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL){
    int rankedID = atoi(row[0]);
    std::vector< int > tempRow;
    tempRow.push_back(atoi(row[0]));
    tempRow.push_back(atoi(row[1]));
    tempRow.push_back(atoi(row[2]));
    myVector.push_back(tempRow);
}
```

I'd like to sort `myVector` by `myVector[i][1]` descending.

Thanks again!

Comment: Use the [sort algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) from the standard library?

Comment: And provide it with an appropriate comparison.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes would you mind providing a code example?  i can sort a 1d vector, but i didn't see an example for a 2d in the link u provided

Comment: @user315052 you lost me.  i'm too new to c++ to know what you mean

Comment: He means `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), your_custom_comparator_that_compares_using_the_relevant_column)`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes ah!  ty!  so what would `comp` be on say `[1]`?  i still don't have close to enough experience to write a custom `comp`.  i only recently discovered descending order via `std::greater<int>()` for a 1d

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy can you show your example of 'by columns'?

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy why do you use multiple dimension? struct of table isn't good for you?

Comment: Given two rows in the 'outer' vector, how do you compare them to order them?  First items unless equal; second items unless equal; third items?

Comment: @billz i'm so new that i have no idea what c++ `table`s are, and i only kinda know what `struct`s are because other code exmpales use them (like the mysql.h example i ripped off).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not too sure exactly what you mean, but I want `myVector` to be sorted by `row[1]` if that's anymore specific

Comment: @a20365354 actually, your first `vector` doesn't need any sorting.  the middle numbers are how i'd like to sort, with highest first to lowest last.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [](const std::vector< int >& a, const std::vector< int >& b){ 
    //If you want to sort in ascending order, then substitute > with <
    return a[1] > b[1]; 
});
```

Please notice that you will need a C++11 compiler to get this code compile. You should make the lambda function accept const references to avoid expensive copies, as suggested by Blastfurnace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    std::vector< std::vector< int > > myVector({{3,4,3},{2,5,2},{1,6,1}});
    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [](const std::vector< int >& a, const std::vector< int >& b){ return a[1] > b[1]; } );

    std::cout << "{";
    for(auto i : myVector){
        std::cout << "[";
        for(auto j : i)
            std::cout << j << ",";
        std::cout << "],";
    }
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the program:

```
{[1,6,1,],[2,5,2,],[3,4,3,],}
```

Comment: Your lambda should take those parameters as `const reference` to avoid expensive copies.

Comment: it gave me `expected primary-expression before â[â token`, `expected primary-expression before â]â token`, `expected primary-expression before âaâ`, and `expected primary-expression before âbâ`

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy that's strange. It seems that your have inserted the character `â` accidentally in the code.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy no, you may not remove the `[]` . This is the syntax of lambda function. If this solution doesn't work for you, then use the one provided by billz.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy: Depending on your compiler you may need to enable `C++11` features like lambdas. For gcc you add `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` to the command line options.

Comment: @Blastfurnace uh oh, i think my c++ is really old. it gave `unrecognized command line option`

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy google `<the name of your compiler> c++11 flag` if you want to use c++11 features. Many useful features are introduced in C++11.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is use struct for table though:

```
struct Table
{
  Table(int c1, int c2, int c3)
  : column1(c1),
    column2(c2),
    column3(c3)
  {
  }

  int column1;
  int column2;
  int column3;  
};
```

Put each row from DB into a struct then store it in vector:

```
std::vector<Table> myVector;
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL)
{
    myVector.push_back(Table(atoi(row[0]), atoi(row[1]), atoi(row[2]));
}
```

Now you could sort vector by any column

```
#include <algorithm>
struct 
{
    bool operator()(const Table& lhs, const Table& rhs)
    {   
      return lhs.column2 > rhs.column2;
    }   
} ColumnLess;

std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), ColumnLess);
```

If you use C++11, could use lambda as well:

```
std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 
         [](const Table& lhs, const Table& rhs){return lhs.column2 < rhs.column2;});
```

Comment: amazing example!  out of curiosity, why would you prefer this over a20365354's (assuming a's works)?

Comment: I am not sure his code will work on multiple dimension vector or not,  I haven't tested it.

Comment: gotcha.  i guess i'm more wondering if a `vector` of `struct`s is more flexible/functional than a `vector` of `vector`s.  re c++11, i'll find out soon enough!  ;))

Comment: yeah, I also added lambda version for my sample, both worked on my test code.

Comment: I would use a plain array or a tuple instead of a struct in this case.

Comment: jeez, i must have a really bad version.  this code gave me `error: no matching function for call to âsort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Table*, std::vector<Table, std::allocator<Table> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Table*, std::vector<Table, std::allocator<Table> > >, <anonymous struct>&)â
`

Comment: you need to `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: i've got `<algorithm>` lol.  i think i need to talk to my sysadmin or something.  my versions probably isn't too far off the CentOS 5.9 default...

Comment: @a20365354 that's putty encoding issue, could set to 'utf-8' characacter set.

Comment: @a20365354 my default was `latin` for some reason.  changed to `utf8`

Comment: @billz +1 for showing me how to have different types in one "subvector" which is what I ended up needing, but I had to give check to konfle because it was the most correct.  thank-you very much!

Comment: @billz in my case, i actually needed the sorted "column" to be a float lol.  less containers = less memory/less cleanup?

Comment: Extra container does use more memory and make code more complicated. And if you sort rows by accident then your code may cause issue. with struct, you can sort by any column :) But it really depends your requirement.