# sort multidimensional vector by 1st column

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I want to quickly sort a multidimensional vector according to the data in the first row. There are ways to do this [(see answers to this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669533/sort-multidimensional-vector-of-ints) but I'm looking for a fast efficient way without using C++11 (i.e., for the 2nd solution provided, I would like to avoid the cost of creating and copying the vectors). I was trying to see if [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html) had a nice sort feature like that of C++11 but am a novice at C++ and unable to figure it out. Essentially, I have data that looks like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > data(2, std::vector<double>(5, 0.0));
data[0][0] = 2.0;  data[1][0] = 4.0;
data[0][1] = 1.0;  data[1][1] = 6.0;
data[0][2] = 3.0;  data[1][2] = 5.0;
data[0][3] = 2.1;  data[1][3] = 3.3;
data[0][4] = 0.3;  data[1][4] = 5.7;
```

and I want to sort the data so that I have

```
data[0][0] = 0.3;  data[1][0] = 5.7;
data[0][1] = 1.0;  data[1][1] = 6.0;
data[0][2] = 2.0;  data[1][2] = 4.0;
data[0][3] = 2.1;  data[1][3] = 3.3;
data[0][4] = 3.0;  data[1][4] = 5.0;
```

Note that I am using vectors since I do not know the dimensions of the data beforehand, however the data will be rectangular and much bigger than the 2x5 example provided here.

Comment: You don't need C++11 to do this. You can write your own comparator functor and utilize [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) regardless. Boost is not required either. see the (2) option in the provided link for how this can be done.

Comment: Do you always use vectors of 3 elements internally? For storing just three doubles (fixed number, small size) `std::vector` might be overkill and costly

Comment: Are you sure that the numbers described in the last block are what you expect? That is not sorted *according to the data in the first column*

Comment: Likewise, now that I stare at the posted expectation, I'm not entirely sure *what* is being sorted. It looks like you sorted the first *vector* and expected matching slots in the remaining vectors (of which there is only one in this sample) to come along for the ride. If that is correct I'm going to drop my answer, because it isn't doing anything like that. (and I concur with David about the overkill. A `std::array` would probably be a better match if they're always 3 slots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, declare a functor:

```
struct FirstColumnOnlyCmp
{
    bool operator()(const std::vector<double>& lhs,
                    const std::vector<double>& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs[0] < rhs[0];
    }
};
```

Then, use it in your `std::sort` invoke:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), FirstColumnOnlyCmp());
```

That's it. C++11 is not required, it just makes such things much much easier since you can do all this in a lambda rather than a functor.

I leave it to you to ensure all vectors in the `data` collection have at least one element to avoid invoking UB (I assume they do, otherwise your logic for comparison may need to get a little more complicated.

Comment: +1, while performance has not been described in the answer, it should be as good as it gets. The `sort` function will use `swap`, which will in turn just exchange three pointers (assuming a stateless allocator). **Update**: Beware: this might not be a correct solution to the ill-posted question. This does not produce the expected output in the question.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I looked at it *twice* and I now see what you're saying. The extra indirection was what thew me. Now I have to gel and see if it is immediately doable like this. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: The question is confusing, as the wording states something different than what the example shows.

Comment: This answer is almost the solution I was looking for. If I reorganize my data so that I have the vector as:
`std::vector<std::vector<double> > data(5, std::vector<double>(2, 0.0));` (i.e. swap the rows & columns) then I can properly perform the sort procedure. Thanks!

Comment: @namu I was wondering whether you had transposed the matrix before (or would have to *after*) if this was going to do what you wanted. Sorry about the confusion of the desired results. It was ... interesting. Glad it helped.