# A function template that can sort object array with respect to any attributes

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, multidimensional-array

I'm the headmaster of a **very large** public school and I've been watching my kids growing up for ten years. Their basic info and test scores each year are stored as follows:

```
class KidInfo{
    string name;
    int age;
    vector<int> score; //The lengths increases as my kids grows up
};

const int NUM = 100000;  //Wow, that's gigantic my friend

KidInfo myKids[NUM];
```

Now I want to analyze these results and create their study profile. To do this I need to sort the array `myKids` by their test scores in descending order each year,  **for ten years**. I have to use `std::sort` to guarentee efficincy since I'm running quite a **large** school.

I'm not a very skillful C++ programmer and have no idea how to handle this task. After checking the answer [sort multidimensional vector by 1st column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978557/sort-multidimensional-vector-by-1st-column), I wrote the following code:

```
bool cmpByYear1(const KidInfo &k1, const KidInfo &k2){
    return k1.score[0] > k2.score[0];
}

bool cmpByYear2(const KidInfo &k1, const KidInfo &k2){
    return k1.score[1] > k2.score[1];
}

//And 8 similiar functions

sort(muKids, myKids + NUM, cmpByYear1);
//print Year 1...
sort(muKids, myKids + NUM, cmpByYear2);
//print Year 2, and so on...
```

It didn't take too long before I got bored writing a new `cmpByYearN` function each year, so I'm thinking about more elegant approaches, like **template**:

```
template<int year>
bool cmpAnyYear(const KidInfo &k1, const KidInfo &k2){
    return k1.score[year - 1] > k2.score[year - 1];
}

int main(){
    //...
    for(int year = 1; year <= 10; ++year){
        sort(myKids, myKids + NUM, cmpAnyYear<year>);
    }
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately my code got compile error with messages like 
`“template parameter "year": local variables cannot be used as non-type parameter...”`.

So I was thinking using a **global** parameter instead:

```
int globalYear = 1;

bool cmpAnyYear(const KidInfo &k1, const KidInfo &k2){
    return k1.score[globalYear - 1] > k2.score[globalYear - 1];
}

int main(){
    //...
    for(; globalYear <= 10; ++globalYear){
        sort(myKids, myKids + NUM, cmpAnyYear);
    }
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

This time my code actually **runs**, but sadly it still doesn't **work**: It looks like the `cmpAnyYear` function was already **fixed** when I declared `globalYear = 1;` and behaved just like `cmpByYear1` regardless of the subsequent changes of `globalYear`. The sorting results remain unchanged from year 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *functor* objects, like e.g.

```
struct cmpAnyYear
{
    cmpAnyYear(int year)
        : year_(year)
    {}

    bool operator()(KindInfo const& k1, KidInfo const& k2) const
    {
        return k1.score[year_ - 1] > k2.score[year_ - 1];
    }

    int year_;
}

int main(){
    //...
    for(int year = 1; year <= 10; ++year){
        sort(myKids, myKids + NUM, cmpAnyYear(year));
    }
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

The expression `cmpAnyYear(year)` constructs a (temporary) object of the type `cmpAnyYear` and passes `year` as argument to the constructor. This object is the "called" as a function, which calls the `cmpAnyYear::operator()` for the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda which captures the `year`:

```
int main()
{
    //...
    for (int year = 1; year <= 10; ++year) {
        sort(myKids, myKids + NUM, [year](const KidInfo& k1, const KidInfo& k2) {
            return k1.score[year - 1] > k2.score[year - 1];
        });
    }
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

---

The reason why `year` as template parameter didn't work is because it has to be a compile-time constant when you call it, which is not in your `for loop`.

Comment: Thanks, but still not quite understand why lambda would work, it still takes the local variable `year` as argument, huh? Does __"compile-time" constant__ mean that the value of the argument should be fixed when the comparing function is created, and that lambda function should becreated just inside `sort`, and destructed before `year` is changed? Hope you could clarify it for me

Comment: @Lotayou You might want to read more about [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). Basically it create a temporary object of a temporary compiler-generated class, and works very much similar to my solution.

Comment: explaining lambdas is outside the scope of this question (and site). There are great resources on the net for explaining and introducing lambdas. As Joachim said, it is more or less a shorthand for his solution.